# @ value of POST variable in PHP CURL

Tags: php, post, curl, special-characters, symbols

I'm creating a function to untilize NameCheap's API for registering domain names.  The registration process worked out smoothly, now I'm looking to set the proper DNS Hosts.

When I create a pure POST request with something like POSTMAN this works fine and returns the expected XML response.  However when I try to pass the data through PHP's CURL functions it breaks.  I've narrowed the problem the the '@' symbol that needs to be passed to the DNS Host. If i put anything else there the request goes through.  I've tried to url_encode the symbol but the API does not accept that.

Any suggestions?

```
public function setDNSHost($name, $server){
    list($domain,$tld) = explode('.',$name,2);
    $request = $this->request_URL;

    $curl = curl_init();

    $args['ApiUser'] = $this->API_User;
    $args['ApiKey'] = $this->API_Key;
    $args['UserName'] = $this->API_User;
    $args['Command'] = 'namecheap.domains.dns.setHosts';

    $args['ClientIP'] = $this->Client_IP;


    $args['SLD'] = $domain;
    $args['TLD'] = $tld;

    $args['HostName1'] = utf8_encode('@');
    $args['RecordType1'] = 'A';
    $args['Address1'] = $server;

    $args['HostName2'] = 'www';
    $args['RecordType2'] = 'CNAME';
    $args['Address2'] = $name;

    $args['HostName3'] = '*';
    $args['RecordType3'] = 'CNAME';
    $args['Address3'] = $name;

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $request,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'API',
        // CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => 1,
         CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
         CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
         CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
         CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $args,
         CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 15
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    // $oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($response);

    return $response;

}
```

Comment: Urlencode and urldecode might be of use?

Answer (score 0):

Some caracters are not allowed to be in the string. To avoid such problems you could use [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/http_build_query) on your data before you use the curl function.